# Change the market for existing ios app

Tags: app-store

Is it possible to change the target market for existing IOS app while doing a version upgrade.
Now its for a particular country. With this upgrade i want to make it world wide.
Is it possible ?

I checked Itunes Connect edit options. But couldn't find any such possibilities.

Thanks for any help!
mia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. It was simple. Don't know why i missed it . In ITunes connect details for your app,  there is Rights and Pricing button. There you can select the app stores. Thats all.

Thanks
mia